# How to create border-bottom?

Tags: html, css

I want to have border-bottom on my active and hover links in navbar.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700;800&family=Quantico:wght@400;700&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Quantico", sans-serif;
}

a {
  font-family: "Quantico", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #111;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

/* Theme */
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-color {
  color: #009603;
}

/* Nav */
nav {
  padding: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav h1 {
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  line-height: 2.5;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 30px 8px;
}

nav ul li a:active,
a:hover {
  border-bottom: #009603 3px solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Pacocha | Garden Projects</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1685e275a4.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div class="container">
          <a href="index.html">
            <h1><i class="fas fa-leaf main-color"></i> Pacocha</h1>
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

But as you can see in my snippet - my border is 1px instead of 3 px. Why?

### I don't know more details I can add.

This is the random text for filler because I believe the question is clear already
This is the random text for filler because I believe the question is clear already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `overflow: hidden` in your `nav`, it hides part of your border, so you can try to increase padding or decrease the height of nav to resolve it.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Your answer helped me

Answer (score 0):

for border on the bottom you simply use `border-bottom: 2px solid red;`

Example

```css
a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
  padding: 5vh;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #4caf5c;
}

a:hover{
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<a>this is a link</a>
```